# Как заставить SAMBA не спрашивать пароль?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, samba

я настраиваю бэкапы по сети, и в какой то момент для облегчения жизни мне понадобилось, чтобы доступ к расшаренной папке был без пароля. И самое главное - без запроса пароля, этого диалога Винды, который показан на картинке:

[image: password dialog]

С тех пор я перебрал несколько вариантов, пытаясь вписать их в файл `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, но ни одна из этих попыток не привела к результату: винда всё равно спрашивает пароль, даже когда я описываю *максимально* доступную шару в самбе, что то вроде

```
    [abackups]
            path = /abackups
            public = yes
            writeable = yes
            browseable = yes
            guest ok = yes
            read only = no
```

Я нашел [пост](https://serverfault.com/questions/630631/), в котором автор решает аналогичную задачу и использует для решения опции `force user = jonnie` и `force group = jonnie`.

Но я так  не понял, что это за jonnie и откуда он взялся. У меня, в отличие от описываемого случая, не ntfs-шара, а просто пустая папка, куда нужно класть бэкапы.

Я попробовал добавить и эти строчки в smb.conf, заменив неведомого jonnie на моё имя в системе, но на результат это никак не повлияло.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую магию нужно прописать в smb.conf, чтобы диалог сзапросом имени и пароля не появлялся, а шара была доступна для записи?**

Привожу для полноты картины свой smb.conf:

```
    [global]         
            workgroup = office
            server string = Samba Server %v         
            netbios name = smallsrv         
            security = user         
            map to guest = bad user         
            name resolve order = bcast host 
            dns proxy = no 

    [konst]
            path = /home/konst/
            valid users = @smbgrp
            guest ok = no
            writeable = yes         
            browseable = yes

    [abackups]
            path = /abackups
            public = yes
            writeable = yes
            browseable = yes
            guest ok = yes
            read only = no
```

====================

Небольшое дополнение.

я уже убил на это столько времени, что мне самому страшно.

я попробовал примерно десяток рецептов, все из которых, видимо, не имеет смысла здесь приводить.

Всегда результат один: при попытке в винде зайти на сетевую шару спрашивается логин и пароль.

Последним, что я попробовал, был такой конфиг, про который автор [пишет](https://serverfault.com/questions/575394/samba-public-share-windows-keeps-asking-for-password) "This is the config that (finally) worked here. ... *This disables any security*. Guest access with write permissions... I can access a linux server from Windows without asking for a user/password:"

и который сводится к довольно банальному в моём случае

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Samba Server %v
    netbios name = tower
    security = user
    map to guest = bad user
    dns proxy = no

#============= Share Definitions =================
[abackups]
    force user = konst
    path = /abackups
    browsable =yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
```

Не знаю, в чем тут дело. Возможно, дело не только в конфиге Самбы. Может быть, все авторы делают *еще что то*, что для них настолько очевидно, что они об этом даже не упоминают в своих ответах. Например, я, каждый раз, переписывая файл `smb.conf`, перезапускаю самбу командой `sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart`. Может, кроме написания файла конфига нужно еще что то делать, чтобы Самба работала, как предполагается. А может, то, что я хочу, в принципе невозможно, и все, кто пишет о том, что у них получилось - ошибаются, и у них просто логин-пароль в винде закешированы. В общем, загадка.

======================================

Дополнение, добавленное еще позже.

Кажется, я заметил **фишку**, которая может иметь отношение к делу.

В общем, этот вход по самбе *по разному* работает на двух компах с виндой.

я *подозреваю*, что всё дело в чертовой паранойе по поводу SMB1, и что все попытки подключиться к шаре кончаются запросом парояля именно потому,Ч то SMB1 не разрешена на том виндовом компе, на котором я эжтой *порнографией* (ну, в хорошем, положительном смысле этого слова) занимаюсь.

Сейчас буду проверять...

Comment: Группа по умолчанию в Windows - WORKGROUP

Comment: Пока что могу только предположить кэш авторизации самой винды. Если в командной строке винды выполнить `net use /d *` а после `net use \\smallsrv\abackups` тоже запрашивает пароль?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev - спасибо за свежую идею, я попробовал - нет, при попытке сделать это через командную строку с предварительным удалением - всё равно спрашивается пароль... Нашел еще такой вопрос-ответ: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619106/ - пробую сделать так же. Там есть загадочная строка passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u -  "имя программы, которую можно использовать для смены паролей UNIX" - вот нахрена, нахрена она в конфиге, когда я в страшном сне никакихз паролей менять не собираюсь?

Comment: что-б-я-помнил-как-оно-настраивается, у меня ещё есть `guest account = nobody` в global секции, пароль не спрашивает для доступа.

Comment: @Мелкий - Спасибо, и это сейчас попробую

Comment: В общем, я попробовал всё, что смог. Не работает. Вспомнил еще одно заклинание, которое досталось нам от мудрых предков: "создавай в винде ив линуксе пользователей с одним и тем же именем и паролем!". Вполне возможно, в этом и заключается магия

Comment: https://smb-conf.ru/absolyutnaya-fajlopomojka.html видел? Пашет? Про `chmod 777 /abackups` не забудь.

Comment: Ты бэкапишь виндовые тачки на линуксовую самба-шару? Я всё правильно понимаю?

Comment: посмотрите [эту ссылку](https://serverfault.com/questions/720332/)

Comment: @donRumata - да, всё правильно, бэкаплю папки с виндовых тачек на линуксовую самба-шару. Про chmod 777 - нет, не забыл. Спасибо за советы!

Comment: Возможно проблема связана с этим (и требуется менять настройки Windows, а не Samba): https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default

Comment: `security = user` из глобала попробуй убрать. Насколько я помню именно он требует ввод пароля. У меня винда 10 на шару файлопомойки с таким же конфигом без `security = user` спокойно пускает без требования пароля

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov - спасибо, свежая мысль! Попробую!